# Re-routing Error asp.net Core with Ocelot (7.0.4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ocelot

```
"ReRoutes": [
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/Agent/GetPagedAgents?page={page}",
  "DownstreamScheme": "http",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "agent.api",
      "Port": 80
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/account/user/list/GetPagedAgents?page={page}",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": []

}]
```

Here I am trying to Re-route my UpstreamPathTemplate to DownstreamPathTemplate from a query string,

```
"http://accountmanagement/api/account/user/list/GetPagedAgents?page=1"
```

this is my query string am sending to my account management service for re-route to my agent service using ocelot.

This is my Controller method in agent service for receiving re-routed path

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetPagedAgents")]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    public IActionResult Get(string page, string pageSize, string filter, 
    string sortBy)
    {
        var Result = _agentServices.GetAll(Convert.ToInt32(page), 
Convert.ToInt32(pageSize),filter,sortBy);

          return Ok(Result);
    }
```

But it's not working. In my OUTPUT window its showing message: Unable to find downstream route for path: /api/account/user/list/GetPagedAgents, verb: GET

that means here it's taking my UpstreamPath as

```
 Upstream url path is /api/account/user/list/GetPagedAgents
```

missing the parameter here.

any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that this url `http://accountmanagement/api/account/user/list/GetPagedAgents?page=1` can reach your action?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add `[FromQuery]` attribute?

```
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] string page, [FromQuery] string pageSize, [FromQuery] string filter, [FromQuery]string sortBy)
{
...
}
```

or create a simple model

```
public class Request
{
   public string Page { get; set; }
   public string PageSize { get; set; }
   public string Filter { get; set; }
   public string SortBy { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like

```
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] Request request)
{
...
}
```